# How to dynamically generate HTML tag attributes in JSP?

Tags: jsp, attributes, jstl, dynamic-forms

I am trying to generate HTML tag attributes in JSP. The below class represents a HTML input element and the `parameters` field represents the tag attributes.

```
public class Input {

    private Map<String, String> parameters;

    public Input() {
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

In my Spring MVC controller I created a list which is to contain the inputs and pass it into my model.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(Model model) {
    List<Input> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    // Creating objects and adding them to the list.
    model.addAttribute("inputs", inputs);
    return "add";
}
```

I've checked and all objects are created correctly. I have a problem with printing them out in the right way in the jsp

```
<c:forEach var="input" items="${inputs}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="${input.parameters['id']}">${input.parameters['title']</label> 
        <input 
            <c:forEach var="param" items="${input.parameters}">
                <c:out value="${param.key}" />=<c:out value="${param.value}" />
            </c:forEach>
        />
        <form:errors path="${input.parameters['name']}" />                      
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

However, the input attributes are not rendered:

```
<input =="="></input>
```

It is not what I expect. What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the bad architectural design, your logic looks fine. Only, the `${param}` is a **reserved** EL variable representing the HTTP request parameter map. E.g. `${param.foo}` prints the `bar` value of `http://example.com/context/page?foo=bar`. See also [our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

Rename `var="param"` to something else and retry. Using "attributes" and "attribute" instead of "parameters" and "param" would make more sense and the code better readable.

```
<c:forEach var="attribute" items="${input.attributes}">
    <c:out value="${attribute.key}" />=<c:out value="${attribute.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```